# VLC installation problem - taking a long time

Tags: video, vlc

I am trying to install the VLC media player from the software centre. It says it is installing, but has been "hanging" for over an hour. 
If I click on the "progress" icon it says "VLC media player Applying changes". 
Closing the software centre, reopening and then clicking on VLC just brings me back to the same VLC media player page saying it's installing.
Internet is working fine. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Any help appreciated

Tim

Comment: To get a better idea of what is actually happening and when and why it is hanging, it might be an idea to install it via Terminal instead, to launch Terminal do CTRL + ALT + T, then execute `sudo apt-get install vlc`, enter your password (even though it won't show that you are entering your password, you are, it just doesn't show it for security reasons), press enter, and then if it asks you if you do want to install, type `y` and press enter, then [edit] the question with the output up to where it gets stuck. That will probably allow us to help you more! :)

Comment: I rebooted my PC again as per looserof7 suggestion, and then tried installing vlc via the Terminal as per yr suggestion. This time it worked OK. Thanks very much for your help.   As an aside - in your opinion what's the nest way to teach myself the commands that I can use in the terminal?  Thanks again

Comment: Well, the way I learn was through lots of research of common commands etc, and writing them all down in a table so that whenever I used a command I would not then forget it, and of course I would also write down what the command does. There is a good course [here](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-the-command-line) on CodeCademy that you might look into (it's free) which should give you the basics and a little more perhaps.

Comment: But if you want to know what a specific command does, you just look at its manualpage/manpage by typing in `man` followed by the command in Terminal (without any options or arguments after the command that is unless you are giving them to `man`, but I wouldn't worry about that right now).

Comment: There is also a very clever system with the commands in Terminal for you can give the commands different 'options' and 'arguments' (this will be all in the `manpages` for the commands), so for instance if I wanted to get the command `ls` to show me the contents of a folder including hidden files and folders, then I would use the `-a` option and then give it the argument of the file or folder which I want to output for (because I could want it to only show me the information for a specific file, or the contents of a directory).

Comment: This would look something like this: `ls -a ~/` which would give me the contents of the home directory for my current user including hidden files and folders, why not give it a go (you may or may not already know that files and folders starting with a `.` in Linux and Unix mean that the file or folder is hidden - on Windows this is done differently though and the hidden flag is put in the item's properties)! I hope all this helps! ;)

Comment: Thanks very much - I'm sure it will help - I'll start by trying out the CodeCademy course. A little later though...
Bye for now

Comment: You're welcome! I hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try running (in Terminal - launch Terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

And then run:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have seen 'Applying changes'

It means that the package have been downloaded and it was being installed.
Some times it takes long time to install some packages.
If at all you were seeing this problem even after 5 to 10 minutes.

Try to shutdown the system and try it doing the same after switching it on.

Comment: I rebooted my PC again as per yr suggestion and this time it worked OK. Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: @Tim: If this answer solved your problem, please click the little grey **☑** under the number now turning it into beautiful green. This means "[yes, this answer is correct](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)"! **;-)**